# How to Unit test CodeIgniter code

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeigniter, testing, activerecord

I need to do unit testing of CodeIgniter. I tried CIUnit but coulnd't get the fixtures set up in v1.7.2.

I tried pure PHPUnit but could not create stub of model class as it was inheriting active-record and it was throwing error that activerecord not found. Obviously there is no controller which loads the activer record helper.

Is there a way to do unit testing in Codeigniter. I know about simple test library but how good is it when compared to phpunit.
Is there any means to do integration testing also.

Comment: Short version: You can't, the Codeigniter framework is preventing unit-tests of the core components as controllers. As your code extends from those core components (derivates), your code is trapped as well and can't form a testable unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FooStack is an add-on that may help you. It includes instructions for fixtures and is compatible with 1.7.2 (which is an old release, BTW).

http://www.knollet.com/foostack/

Comment: thanks, I tried foostack and with some hurdles was able to run test functions. Though I have few issues remaining. How do I test a function which uses $_POST data. Also the example provided for ViewAllTests seems complex, is there a simple method to test a single view.

Comment: Take this advice with a grain of salt, since I don't actually use foostack myself, but you should be able to use native PHP to set the $_POST array values you need in your test.

Comment: Dan's advice works for this. In Foostack, you set up your POST array and then trigger the controller method. The built-in CI post functions just use the POST array you set up. Throw in a bunch of Mock objects and a dash of Setup/Teardown and you're good to go.